# deploying a Qt application

Tags: qt, deployment, portability

*In a nutshell, the question is: I just finished my first application using Qt Creator on a computer running under Linux Ubuntu, now how do I make this available for everyone. Now follows the more detailed version ;)*

I must apologize for asking this, I am aware that this question has probably been asked many times and that there is official documentation that I can read. I am just completely new to programming and I am very confused by everything I've read so far. If you are kind enough to help, please assume I know absolutely nothing :)

Here we go: I've just finished designing my first application (a scientific program) with Qt creator on my laptop which runs under Linux Ubuntu. It works fine and I'm very proud of it ;)

Here's what my project consists of: 40 header files, 42 source files, 1 pro file, 1 qrc file, 1 html file and 7 png files. In the code, I use `#include` for a bunch of fairly standard Qt classes (`QWidget`, `QTextBrowser` and so forth, maybe like 40 of those).

Now I'd like to make it available to other people. For Linux and Mac users, I've figured a way to do that: I can compress the folder containing my project, tell them to install Qt on their computer, then download and extract the files on their hard disk, open a terminal in the folder and run

```
qmake myProject.pro
qmake
make
```

That seems to work fine (by the way, does it matter that this is not precisely what Qt creator does? The `qmake` step there is `qmake-qt4 myProject.pro -r -spec linux-g++` and the make step is `make -w`). Now, I assume there is a solution where I don't ask them to download and install something like 200Mo of Qt material. As for Microsoft Windows users, I don't have a clue.

I would be very grateful if you could explain to me in a very concrete way what I need to do. Needless to say, I'll go for the best and easiest solution, I don't need to understand everything about deployment. Many thanks in advance!

Edit: In case that's useful : I've been using Qt Creator 2.5.0 based on Qt 4.8.1 (64 bit), I'm working on a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 64bits

Answer (score 3):

For Linux and Mac users, I would compile the software for them in 32 and 64bit formats - no-one likes compiling unknown software from source.  Obviously keep the source code option for those on more unusual architectures/OSs (and provide a shell script for them that mimics the commands Qt Creator calls!).  As Qt runtimes are available from package managers on just about *every* distro (and come pre-installed on most anyway, KDE requires them for example), by not asking them to compile from source your users will have a much smaller download (if any) and won't require them to download software from a website potentially unknown to them.  Of course the best way would be to try to get your software added as a package into the major distros' repositories, but that may take some time to organise.

Compile your software for Windows users for both 32 and 64bit formats.  It's generally frowned upon to ask users to download runtime libraries they potentially don't know, and put them into their system32 folder...  So most applications bundle *all* the libraries they need with their application.  Qt-based applications are no different, and so put the runtimes into the folder where the executable is.  Also it is much more professional to create a proper installer, there are a few free installer applications for Windows, a web search will give you the most popular (I think I saw a thread on SO about it as well).

As you can see the platforms aren't too dissimilar, the main point I would make is: **Do not force people to compile from source!**  The vast majority of people on Earth do not even know what compiling *is*, so provide for the major arrchitectures/OSs yourself.

Comment: OK, I just did. But to be honest, from a practical point of view I haven't made much progress...